# Disable logging through ini_set() in PHP?

Tags: php, error-log, access-log, ini-set

I would like to disable logging (`access_log` and `error_log`) on my server. Is this possible through the function `ini_set()`? If it is, how do you do it?

Comment: you can't disable access_log/error_log out of php cause it is a Webserver (e.g. Apache) function. You can only change PHP-Error handling.

Comment: I see. I guess it's only possible to disable the errors that PHP wants to add to the error log, am I correct?

Comment: yes... may there is some "hack" but that depends on your software environment. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to disable access log too?